# How to divide EAR package into modules

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, jsf-2, ear

I have a simple JSF application packaged as EAR file. This is the directory structure.

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── SR_57-ear
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── application
│               └── META-INF
│                   └── MANIFEST.MF
├── SR_57-ejb
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   ├── java
│       │   │   └── com
│       │   │       └── SR_57
│       │   └── resources
│       │       └── META-INF
│       │           └── MANIFEST.MF
│       └── test
│           └── java
│               └── com
│                   └── SR_57
└── SR_57-web
    ├── pom.xml
    └── src
        ├── main
        │   ├── java
        │   │   └── com
        │   │       └── SR_57
        │   │           └── user_check.java
        │   ├── resources
        │   └── webapp
        │       ├── home.xhtml
        │       ├── index.html
        │       ├── resources
        │       │   ├── css
        │       │   │   ├── sr_style.css
        │       │   │   └── style.css
        │       │   ├── images
        │       │   │   ├── 1.jpg
        │       │   │   ├── 2.jpg
        │       │   │   ├── 3.jpg
        │       │   │   ├── 4.jpg
        │       │   │   ├── 5.jpg
        │       │   │   ├── 6.jpg
        │       │   │   ├── 7.jpg
        │       │   │   ├── bg_1.jpg
        │       │   │   ├── bg.jpg
        │       │   │   ├── overlay_1.png
        │       │   │   ├── overlay.png
        │       │   │   ├── title_1.png
        │       │   │   └── title.png
        │       │   └── js
        │       │       ├── ChunkFive_400.font.js
        │       │       ├── cufon-yui.js
        │       │       ├── jquery.easing.1.3.js
        │       │       └── jquery.min.js
        │       ├── sr.xhtml
        │       └── WEB-INF
        │           ├── faces-config.xml
        │           ├── java.sql.Driver
        │           └── web.xml
        └── test
            └── java
                └── com
                    └── SR_57
```

For now I have only 2 JSF pages and one managed bean into the SR_57-web module. I want to place the bean into the SR_57-ejb module and cut it into small .jar files. The problem is that I don't have an idea how to write the code which assembles the modules.

Can you explain me how I can do that?

Comment: Do you use a build tool like gradle, ant or maven?

Comment: Yes I use Maven but I use Netbeans 7.1 to edit and build the EAR file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With maven the maven assembly plugin (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) is a way to assemble. But you can also use the maven antrun plugin (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) to copy and move your files.